# Como utilizar uma variável global para um link

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando utilizar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para facilitar o uso de links onde poderia chamar a variável em qualquer diretório do site. Para usar com o `include($pagina_inicial)` funciona, mas para link não funciona:

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
$pagina_inicial = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/index.php';
?>
<a href="<?php $pagina_inicial ?>">Link</a>
// Seria o equivalente disso:
<a href="www.site.com/index.php">Link</a>
// Mas está retornando assim: 
// http://www.site.com/home/u711323471/public_html/index.php
```

Alguém sabe me informar como consigo fazer isso??

Comment: O melhor é usar caminhos relacionasod. Por exemplo `/` é root. Assim pode fazer somente `$pagina_inicial = '/index.php';` e noutra diretoria: `$pagina_inicial = '/outra_dir/index.php';`

Comment: O que o Sergio disse, mas aqui vai um snippet útil para inspecionar variáveis: `printf( '<pre><code>%s</code></pre>', print_r( $_SERVER, true ) );`

Comment: A resposta é, não use dessa forma.. O motivo é que não faz sentido pois é uma variável global e praticamente constante. Siga conselho do @Sergio

Comment: Vou utilizar dessa forma mesmo. Obrigado Sergio e cia pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com [sugeri antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34869/como-utilizar-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-global-para-um-link?noredirect=1#comment67510_34869), o melhor é usar caminhos relacionados.

Por exemplo `/` é root. Assim pode fazer somente `$pagina_inicial = '/index.php';` e noutra diretoria: `$pagina_inicial = '/outra_dir/index.php';`

Ou não usar variáveis de php e fazer:

```
<a href="/index.php">Link</a> // se o ficheiro estiver na root
<a href="/../index.php">Link</a> // se o ficheiro estiver numa descendente direta da root
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar o `HTTP_HOST`ou o `SERVER_NAME`, acredito que eles vão passar a variável da maneira que você quer.

Caso tenha dúvidas, o PHP Manual tem uma página somente para as funções `$_SERVER`, [da uma olhada aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php).